# Confused with paths and files and source folders

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently stumbled upon this predicament I can't figure out.

Say I want to load a text file, and have it in my JAR.
In eclipse it goes "res/txt/text.txt"
However, since res/ is a source folder, on exporting apparently it goes txt/text.txt
Now, if I try to load that for debugging in Eclipse,

```
new File("txt/text.txt");
```

I get an IOException, since in Eclipse it's located in res/txt/text.txt

What part am I missing? I thought it was bad convention to put files from Res folder in the directory as src folder? Am I wrong?

Also, differences between extracting and packaging required libraries upon export of runnable jar?

EDIT:
I also have a loose file in the "res/" folder called "log.txt"
I normally, and successfully access it using

```
File logFile = new File("res/log.txt");
```

But now, it creates the file (which is done if it doesn't exist), directly in the project folder, outside of the res folder.

YES, res is a Source folder in the Build path

### Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is txt/ also a source folder? Source folders are simply used for organization in eclipse - All are removed and moved up to the deepest package or real folder above when compiling to a jar.

If txt/ is a source folder then simply reference "text.txt"

Comment: @snickers10m no it's actually not, which confuses me further, I seem to especially be getting an error at if !file.exists() file.createNewFile() which didn't happen before the "res/" change